# Atom - HTML code turns gray when copying and pasting

Tags: html, atom-editor, color-scheme

I have this weird issue where when I copy and paste into my index.html file in atom, it makes the html code turn gray. This issue only happens when I copy and paste. I've looked through stack overflow and the general answer is make sure my settings are correct which they are. Additionally, some of my code remains colored but some doesn't so it's like it recognizes some of it, but not all of it. I attached a picture. Everything in the code was copied and pasted, but for some reason it turned gray halfway down. If anyone has ever had this problem, let me know what you did to fix it.[image]

Comment: Please post your code directly to question, no need of adding extra URLs or images that can become invalid in future.

Comment: There's no need to post my code. I was just trying to show how the code turns from being colored to gray for no reason and I don't know what's causing that.

Comment: While I broadly agree that the image illustrates your problem, it does prevent us from easily copying and pasting said code into our own IDEs, which might help us to identify the relevant problem. Also, the text in an image isn't searchable so it limits the options for non-, or partially-, sighted individuals to help.

Comment: Agreed. Sorry. I made a new post with the same question with my code. To give some background, I don't think this has anything to do with code. Anytime I copy and paste anything into Atom regardless of what project I'm working on, the coloring issue happens. In the next comment I'll link to the new question.

Comment: Here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65765380/atom-html-code-turns-gray-when-copying-and-pasting-updated-with-code